# In mySQL, how to define a user-defined function of a row of attributes?

Tags: mysql, function, row, user-defined-functions

Suppose there is a schema R(a,b), my target schema is S(a, b, foo(a,b)), where foo is supposed to be a self-defined function. Is there a good way to achieve this goal? like 
S = SELECT a, b, foo(a, b) FROM R.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly that, using [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-procedure.html), followed (if necessary) by [`CREATE VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-view.html):

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION foo ... ;
DELIMITER ;

CREATE VIEW S AS SELECT a, b, foo(a, b) FROM R;
```

Or, to create a snapshot of `S`, use [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-select.html):

```
CREATE TABLE S SELECT a, b, foo(a, b) FROM R;
```

Of course, if you don't need to use `foo()` anywhere else, you might simply be able to express its value within the `SELECT` statement (but that seems too basic to be a question):

```
SELECT a, b, a+b FROM R;
```